# Using MCMC-derived posterior to design variational approximation function

Tags: hierarchical-bayesian, variational-bayes, probabilistic-programming, variational-inference

I am trying to fit a hierarchical model that estimates the covariance of some parameters, using the probabilistic programming language pyro.

In simulation experiments, I saw that the MCMC generates good posterior samples that estimate the ground truth covariance well. However, to scale up the model to high-dimensional data, I was trying to design a variational approximation (guide) to implement stochastic variational inference (SVI). Standard mean-field approximations do not yield correct estimates, so I think that they are not complex enough to describe the posterior.

In order to understand which latent variables interactions to include in the approximation, would it make sense to look for these interactions in the posterior samples generated with MCMC and generalizing those to the high-D settings?

In other words, let's say that I look into the MCMC posterior samples and observe that there is an approximately linear relationship between variables $A$ and $B$, I could impose this same relationship in the variational approximation.

I have never heard of this approach, as usually I knew that one tends to use SVI to get a fast approximate fit and then MCMC to refine, whereas this would be the reverse process.

Comment: i suppose the natural question is: if you can use MCMC to find the true relationship between the variables, what good is a subsequent variational analysis which has these constraints imposed? It sounds like you could have been done after the MCMC step.

Comment: the idea is that I am just prototyping basic relationships between variables in the 2-variable case, but then I would extend to 1000s of variable case, where the hierarchical relationships would be still similar. Also, in this case I know the true relationship between variables (so, the model) because I am generating synthetic data. Even in that case, I am having a hard time figuring out the induced relationships between variables in the posterior.